# How should i differentiate a service with a model in a project?

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller

It's confusing to categorize something into a model, and others into services. Is their any good thumb rule, help of which i may distinguish between a service and a model. I tried to look into various mvc docs, but almost all of them talk about model-view-and controller. Nothing about services.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look at Robotlegs.

It is an ActionScript MVC(S) framework that promotes looser coupling between components, and has hooks to handle models and services accordingly.
Rules of thumb to distinguish whether to use a Service or a Model are described thoroughly in the documentation.

In short, a Service would be used to connect your application to the outside world, thus bringing external state into your application.
Whereas a Model would be used to store internal application state.

Robotlegs also features a handy IOC container.

You will be able to either implement your application with this framework or you could get a lot of ideas from looking at the framework code.

Check these out:
http://www.robotlegs.org/
http://www.robotlegs.org/diagram/

Comment: For more informations about Robotlegs services and models take a look at "ActionScript Developer's Guide to Robotlegs" book. There's whole chapter about this subject ("Chapter 7. Models and services: How are they different?").

Comment: Thnx. Actually, coincidentally i was going through the same chapter. And was looking at one of the examples : The "MosaicTools" one. Isn't it possible that a "service" is independent of "model" ? Tht's it only affects a view, instead of a model ?

Comment: Well yes and no. A `Service` can be independant of a `Model`. However, one would never inject (or set) a Service directly into a View. The way to go would be to have your mediator trigger a command, which in turn gets data from your service. Your command would then pass the service result as a parameter in a custom application event that any mediator can catch and then update the view accordingly. This is what MVCS is all about, seperation of concerns.